# Want to achieve a functionality similar to dict

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I am new to TCL. I want to create TCL dictionary like structure which have string keys. I want to count occurrences of certain types in the dictionary, hence i would want to update the dictionary at a specific index (index is the string). How to achieve this?

> Example: (Logical not with exact tcl syntax)
>
> a['hello'] = 0, 
>   a['hi'] = 0
>   Now if hello is found in the data i am scanning, I would like to
>   update a['hello'] = a['hello'] + 1;

Please help me with syntax to achieve this. I am using tcl version less than 8.5 which does not support dict.

Comment: Checked out the [man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) first?

Comment: Tcl6 is very old. I don't think it has the bytecompiler implemented. Tcl got a huge speed boost in 8.0.

Comment: Yes, i know but i could not upgrade, it is running on some legacy.

Comment: 6.10? There never was such a version of Tcl (and if there was, it would have been over 20 years old, which is a _bit_ unlikely). I suspect you've found some other version number there. `info patchlevel` will report the actual Tcl version, as will `package require Tcl` (unless you're in something really old).

Comment: Ok..yes quite possible, however the version i am using doesn't support dict. Hence I have modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware that dictionaries are supported from version 8.5 onwards. So I could not use the dict commands in my script.

Therefore I am using associative arrays (HashMaps) for this purpose.

Example:

```
set a(hello)0
set a(hi)    0

set a(hello) [expr $a(hello) + 1]
```

To iterate through the associative array:

```
foreach key [array names a] {
    set count [expr $a($key)]
    puts $count
}
```

Comment: You can still replace the code in the first code block (specifically the first and last line) with `incr a(hello)`. The single quotes have no syntactic function, so if you don't need them for some other purpose, just drop them. Also, `[expr $a($key)]` is the same as `$a($key)`.

Comment: Without expr I observed an error, hence I used that. Regrading single quotes, thanks will update it.

Comment: That is very surprising, since `expr` does nothing to catch or fix any errors (the way you've written it, it will perform double evaluation, but that shouldn't make any difference if you're only dealing with integers). If `$a($key)` works as an argument for `expr`, there is no obvious reason for it not to work as an argument for `set`.

Answer (score 1):

**dict incr dictionaryVariable key ?increment?**

> This adds the given increment value (an integer that defaults to 1 if
>   not specified) to the value that the given key maps to in the
>   dictionary value contained in the given variable, writing the
>   resulting dictionary value back to that variable. Non-existent keys
>   are treated as if they map to 0. It is an error to increment a value
>   for an existing key if that value is not an integer. The updated
>   dictionary value is returned.

```
% set myinfo {firstName Dinesh lastName S age 25}
firstName Dinesh lastName S age 25
% dict incr myinfo age; # This will increase the value of 'age' by 1 which is default
firstName Dinesh lastName S age 26
% dict incr myinfo age 10; # OMG!!!, I'm old already...
firstName Dinesh lastName S age 36
% dict incr myinfo count; # Using non-existing key name will create a key with that name
firstName Dinesh lastName S age 36 count 1
% dict incr myinfo count -1; # Even negative values can be used
firstName Dinesh lastName S age 36 count 0
%
```

**Reference :** [dict incr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm#M14)